# REST on *just* IIS7 (without a web framework)

Tags: rest, iis-7, webdav, webrequest

I want to upload files directly to IIS7 (in this case I am using the WebRequest object in .NET). Thus I need IIS7 to accept POST, PUT, and DELETE verbs such that I can upload and delete files on the server directly. Is it possible to have IIS accept files without a a web framework like ASP.NET? Essentially I want to be able to use IIS (HTTP) as an FTP server.

Comment: First, what's the question?   you haven't asked one.   Second, clarify what you mean by "*just* IIS7".   You need some sort of code on IIS7.  IIS7 will hand-off the POST, PUT, DELETE (and I presume GET...?) to an application, which you provide.

Comment: Sorry for the ill-formed question. I just need to be able to have a file server over HTTP. Right now I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Is that for updating the web site? Like replacing HTML files using an FTP client? Or is it something used by the site visitors to submit files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like IIS pretty much assumes that you're going to be passing request to some kind of handler.